# HTML Canvas Interval, CanvasPattern dissapears

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When creating an HTML canvas I was planning on making these cylinders and animating marbles moving inside them. However, when trying to do so it would just delete everything. After messing around with my code, I discovered the problem was due to the `fillStyle` which was a `CanvasPattern` from an image.

This snippet simulates exactly what I am experiencing. The rectangle draws perfectly fine, however, after 1 second, when the interval runs, it disappears and there is no arc or "marble" drawn. There are no errors in console either

**With Interval (Not working):**

```js
let canv = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

let matte = new Image(canv.width, canv.height);
matte.onload = function() {
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(matte, 'repeat');
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fill();
};
matte.src = "https://www.muralswallpaper.com/app/uploads/classic-red-marble-textures-plain-820x532.jpg"; // An image src
ctx.lineWidth = "5";

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50); // This dissapears when the setInterval runs???? Marble doesn't even draw

let x = 60,
  y = 20;
var draw = setInterval(function() { // Drawing the marble

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  y += 1;
}, 1 * 1000);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

When I get rid of the interval it would work, but when the interval is there, nothing is drawn.
I have absolutely no idea why this is happening and I cannot find anything on the internet regarding this problem. Is there a way I can animate this marble while having the image continue to mask its `fillStyle`??

**Without Interval (Working):**

```js
let canv = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

let matte = new Image(canv.width, canv.height);
matte.onload = function() {
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(matte, 'repeat');
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fill();
};
matte.src = "https://www.muralswallpaper.com/app/uploads/classic-red-marble-textures-plain-820x532.jpg"; // An image src
ctx.lineWidth = "5";

ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50); // This dissapears when the setInterval runs???? Marble doesn't even draw

let x = 60,
  y = 20;
//var draw = setInterval(function() { // Drawing the marble

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  y += 1;
//}, 1 * 1000);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Things I've tried:

- Got rid of `beginPath` and `closePath`, doesn't make anything disappear but doesn't display arc
- Recreating pattern inside the interval
- Making the fillstyle a colour for everything (Works)
- Making the fillstyle of the marble a colour (Doesnt work)

**EDIT:** After looking some more, I believe the problem is in the `globalCompositeOperation`. It's what deals with the pattern intersecting the drawing. When looking at all the types, `source-in` is the only one that satisfies my expected result, however, it's not working in this situation weirdly.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that your `ctx.rect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);` does nothing: it's the size of the entire canvas, and doesn't fill/stroke anything (`rect()` does not color any pixels on its own). Then, your first `fillRect(0,0,50,50)` will run before you're guaranteed to _have_ a pattern, and the draw() code will start running before your image is guaranteed to have loaded, too, so there's all kinds of nondeterministic logic here. Start by "starting everything" in that load handler, e.g. https://jsbin.com/jucohobuxu/edit?js,output

Comment: @Kamermans I fill that rect right after making the fillStyle to the pattern when the image loads. Run the snippet, what you're saying is wrong

Comment: So you are: look at that jsbin anyway.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you! This works. I still wonder why my method did not though if you have an idea?

Comment: Revisiting the code: your globalCompositeOperation told the context to [make everything transparent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) (why did you pick `source-in`, out of curiosity?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I had used source-in since it acted like a mask for every circle I drew had the texture. I didn't know just setting the fillStyle as the pattern was a much simpler and better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` instruction. Using `source-in`, you're explicitly telling the canvas to make anything that's a different color from the new thing you're drawing (on a per pixel basis) [transparent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation). Since *every* pixel is different, *everything* becomes transparent and you're left with what looks like an empty canvas (even if the `ImageData` will show RGBA data in which the RGB channels have meaningful content, but A is 0).

Remove the `globalCompositeOperation` rule and you're good to go, but you should probably take some time to rewrite the logic here, so that nothing happens until your image is loaded, because your code is pretty dependent on that pattern existing: wait for the image to load, the build the pattern, assign it to the context, and *then* start your draw loop.

```js
const canv = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

let x = 60, y = 20;

function start() {
  const matte = new Image(canv.width, canv.height);
  matte.addEventListener(`load`, evt => 
    startDrawing(ctx.createPattern(matte, 'repeat'))
  );
  matte.addEventListener(`load`, evt => 
    console.error(`Could not load ${matte.src}...`);
  );
  matte.src = "https://www.muralswallpaper.com/app/uploads/classic-red-marble-textures-plain-820x532.jpg"; // An image src
}

function startDrawing(pattern) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = `red`;
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  setInterval(() => {
    draw();
    y += 10;
  }, 1 * 1000);  
}

function draw() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();  
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

// and kick everything off
start();
```

Although on another note, normally setInterval is not the best choice for animations: you usually want [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead, with a "wall time" check (e.g. doing things depending on the actual clock, instead of trusting intervals):

```
...

function startDrawing(pattern) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = `red`;
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  startAnimation();
}

let playing, lastTime;

function startAnimation() {
  playing = true;
  lastTime = Date.now();
  requestAnimationFrame(nextFrame);
}

function stopAnimation() {
  playing = false;
}

function nextFrame() {
  let newTime = Date.now();
  if (newTime - lastTime >= 1000) {
    draw();
  }
  if (playing) {
    lastTime = newTime;
    requestAnimationFrame(nextFrame);
  }
}

...
```

https://jsbin.com/wawecedeve/edit?js,output